# android and ads

Tags: android, admob, adwhirl

Alright, I've done my googling and found [this](http://malsandroid.blogspot.com/2010/05/admob-and-adwhirl.html) article to help me out with my small app. However, that one is getting old so I just have to ask, do I really need admod and adwhirl accounts and jars to display simple google ads?
From what I understand I could have used simple adsense .. if my app was a webapp, which it isn't.
Are all those steps still necesarry?

regards

Comment: Regarding AdSense for mobile, I believe that google's AdSense program is still beta, and available only to users from USA.

Comment: I read something about Adsene for mobile, but thought that it would be discontinued when they bought admob?

Answer (score 1):

I just setup AdMob in my Android application for the first time last night.  I used [their developer guide](http://www.admob.com/docs/AdMob_Android_SDK_Instructions.pdf) and it was really easy to get everything setup and working.  It only took like 30-45 mins start to finish (in an app I already had written).

I didn't feel like it was too much setup.

Comment: I walked through that also. It worked the first times but now it keep saying there are no ads available??

Comment: @elwis - yeah, they talk about the fact that you might not get ads on a live account.  "When you disable test mode, live ads may not be returned immediately for requests from a new publisher ID or one that has not been used in the past 24 hours. You should begin seeing more live ads returned about 15 minutes after your initial live
ad requests."

Answer (score 0):

If you just want Admob or adsense ads, then you certainly don't need to use AdWhirl.  The main reason to use ad mediators and other ad networks is to get better paying ads (or make sure you get a higher fill rate).